# Sharepoint Drive Delta token does not reflect public link changes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Graph delta tokens can be placed on drive root folders. For OneDrive root folders, the delta request will return an item when a public link is added on the folder. But for Sharepoint site root folders, this doesn't happen. No item is returned when fetching a delta.

Not sure if this is a bug or a missing feature.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the feature currently. There is an existing [uservoice entry](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/39203674-send-a-delta-link-item-when-public-links-are-creat) that you can vote for. It'll also keep you up to date with any decision/progress.